# Aspect ratio divs with CSS background images

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design, responsive-images

I have images of equal aspect ratios (300px x 255px) in divs taking up ~31% of the width to make 3 columns on desktop/tablet, then full width on mobile. The images scale to 100% within the div, with the height set as auto. I need to change them from img tags to background images

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYagJd

```
**HTML:**
<div class="hotels">
    <img src="http://www.telodesign.com/test/cavallo-300.jpg" alt=""><br>
Here's a title
</div>

<div class="hotels">
    <img src="http://www.telodesign.com/test/cavallo-300.jpg" alt=""><br>
Here's a title
</div>

<div class="hotels">
    <img src="http://www.telodesign.com/test/cavallo-300.jpg" alt=""><br>
Here's a title
</div>

**CSS:**
.hotels {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 31.8%;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-bottom: 22px;

}

*emphasized text*.hotels img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Is there a way to make these images background images, and still have the aspect ratio dictate the height of the div--allowing the same responsive scaling? I'm hoping there's a way to do this without using .js, if possible. Can it be done with just CSS? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use % to set a padding taking width for reference to keep ratio.
example :
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNXgJp  or http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VvKPMM (demos below)

```css
.hotels {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 31.8%;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-bottom: 22px;
  background: url(http://www.telodesign.com/test/cavallo-300.jpg) no-repeat red;
  background-size: 100% auto;
}
.hotels:before {
  content: '';
  padding-top: 85%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="hotels">
  Here's a title</div>

<div class="hotels">
  Here's a title</div>

<div class="hotels">
  Here's a title</div>
```

or

```css
.hotels {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 31.8%;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-bottom: 22px;
  background: url(http://www.telodesign.com/test/cavallo-300.jpg) no-repeat red;
  background-size: 100% auto;
}
.hotels:before {
  content: '';
  padding-top: 85%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  margin-left: -0.25em;
}
p {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="hotels">
  <p>Here's a title</p>
</div>

<div class="hotels">
  Here's a title</div>

<div class="hotels">
  Here's a title</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, GCyrillus. I'm a little confused as to what, exactly, is happening here--even after playing with the CodePen... but it most certainly works! So is the top padding forcing that height of the div, then? What's the purpose of the -.25 em margin-left? Thanks in any case for a great solution to a frustrating problem!

Comment: @hudsonian take a look at http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#padding-properties (see what % values inplies same for margin actually). the pseudo élément is here to stretch your box (wich is actually a min-height cause it can still grow/expand taller)

Answer (score 1):

You could try using view widths to keep the proportions on resize:

```
HTML
<div class="hotels">
Here's a title</div>

<div class="hotels">
Here's a title</div>

<div class="hotels">
Here's a title</div>

CSS

.hotels {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 31.8vw;
  height: 26.3vw;
  vertical-align: top;
    margin-bottom: 22px;
  background-image:url(http://www.telodesign.com/test/cavallo-300.jpg);
   background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Ash--are there downsides to that--like browser support, e.g.? I've never heard of view width before.

Comment: You could use % instead if you want to support older browsers