# How To Resize A Div & Keep The Aspect Ratio

Tags: html, css

I have a div that will have a background image of the size 1170px x 929px. As I resize the width i.e. shrink it, I would like the height to also shrink so that the aspect ratio is kept. Can someone explain how this can be done using CSS? All I have so far is the following

```
<section class="box">
            <article class="container ">
                <div class="content margin_tp_80 margin_bm_40 map_london">
                </div>
            </article>
        </section>
```

Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: background-size: contain;

Comment: Could this be of any help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32745499/aspect-ratio-divs-with-css-background-images

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap has class which will do it for you.

```
<img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://healthintelasia.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/asia-1500-X-600-banner.jpg" alt="First slide">
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be what you are looking for, the width and height always keep the same ratio

```css
.box{
  position: relative;
 width: 100%; //width of your background image
  }
 .box:before{
  content: "";
 display: block;
 padding-top: 79.4%; //the ration (929/1170)*100
  }
  .container {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<section class="box">
      <article class="container">     
          <div class="content margin_tp_80 margin_bm_40 map_london">
          </div>
      </article>
</section>
```