# Resizing background image with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have to load an (header) image at the top of the site depending on a variable passed in to the site. I can do this but I can only do this if it is a background image, as far as I know.

This is what I am doing in the css for the load of the image:

```
#headerimg 
{
  background-image: url('/Content/CompanyFiles/spi/image3.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  width: 600px;
  height: 133px;   
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

and my html code:

```
@using MvcBootstrap.MiscClasses
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
  @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
  <link href="@Url.Content(string.Format("~/Content/CompanyFiles/{0}/{0}.css?t={1}", MySession.CssName, DateTime.Now.Millisecond))" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>

  <div class="img-responsive" id="headerimg"></div>

<div class="content">

  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h2>Payment Portal</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
    <footer>
      <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year</p>
    </footer>
  </div>

  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
  @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

If I change the css to 100% size, that div isn't shown since there is no content and the image is just a background image, so it collapses.

If I set the div to a specific size, then it stays that size and it will not resize on the page resize.

I need to be able to dynamically insert an image in there based on the css page loaded but resize if used on a smaller device.

Is this possible? Thank you!

Comment: You can calculate the aspect ratio of the image and use padding-top in % of the aspect ratio. So this will maintain your background image aspect ratio in all device.

Comment: Here is the reference for the same http://stackoverflow.com/a/32745727/5609596

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how you use a responsive background image, divide `height` by `width` and multiply by `100`. That will be your bottom padding. Then use `cover` for `background-size:` so it will stretch with the element.

```css
header {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: gold;
}
.hero {
  padding-bottom: 37.5%; /* = ( 600 / 1600 ) x 100 */
  background-image: url( 'http://placehold.it/1600x600/A00' );
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<div class="hero"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll give that a try!

Comment: Works perfectly!! TYVM!